# Function points measure for a business applications framework. Is that possible?

Tags: measurement, software-evaluation, function-point

So, my boss wants to have a complexity measure for a framework developed internally in our company. Is that possible?

As far as I know, functions points do not apply to software that doesn't have persistence per se, and also doesn't have GUI's (it's a framework, built in C#, useful for crafting business applications, and it's used only internally). Also, function points tend to get less useful as the target software being assesed gets more complex.

If it is possible to do this, could someone give me some guidance? If not, how do I convince my boss to stop asking this? Is there a better metric for valuing such a complex software?

Answer (score 1):

first, read more about [function points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point) to dispel the misinformation implied in your question

second, the usefulness of a metric lies in **how it is used**; FP may or may not be useful, it depends on what the purpose of the measurement is